# Executing SQL statements using for loop

Tags: sql, ms-access

Getting error

> number of destination columns and queries are not same...

Please help

```
db.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\New folder (2)\cri.mdb;Persist Security Info=False")
s1 = "select MAX(teamid) from player"
Set rs = db.Execute(s1)
v = rs(0)
For Index = 1 To 2

db.Execute ("insert into player values('" & Str(v) & "' ,'" & p1(Index).Text & "'," & age1(Index).Text & "," & avg1(Index).Text & ")")

Next Index
db.Close
```

Comment: When I have seen this it usually this means that the number of VALUES supplied doesn't match the columns you are trying to insert into.  You didn't supply a list of columns so I cant say for sure.

Comment: Right now you are supplying 4 values to be inserted, which will work fine as long as there are only 4 columns in that table. If there are more, you need to specify which columns you are inserting to like: `INSERT INTO player (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, value4)`.